# Code not creating SQLite database successfully

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a database and run my app on my android phone as my emulator doesn't work. I made some changes in my previous database that was working perfect. I just added another create table query in my code. Now it isn't creating database. I changed the name of db as well. But no result!! Plus i am unable to access `data` folder in my DDMS. Any suggestions or help will be appreciable.

**Code**

```
public class DatabaseWrapper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //For user table
    public static final String FUNTUBE= "User";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UNAME = "_username";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_EMAIL = "_email";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_PASSWORD = "_password";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_FNAME="_fname";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_LNAME = "_lname";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_PHONE="_phone";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_COUNTRY = "_country";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_GENDER = "_gender";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH= "_videopath";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_BDAY = "_bday";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_YEAR = "_year";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_INTEREST = "_interest";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_RELIGION = "_religion";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_ABOUT="_about";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_QUOTE="_qoute";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_JOB = "_job";

    //for UploadFile table

    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE= "UploadFile";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_SIZE = "_size";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_CONTENTTYPE = "_contentType";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_EXTENSION = "_extension";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_CONTENT = "_content";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_LABEL = "_label";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_DATEUPLOADED = "_dateUploaded";
    public static final String FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_USERNAME = "_userName";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);

    }


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FunTubeApplication.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // creation SQLite statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +FUNTUBE
            + "(" + FUNTUBE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            + FUNTUBE_UNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_EMAIL + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_PASSWORD + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_FNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_LNAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_PHONE + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_COUNTRY + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_GENDER + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_VIDEOPATH + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_BDAY + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_YEAR + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_INTEREST + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_RELIGION + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_ABOUT + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_QUOTE + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_JOB+ " text not null)";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table " +FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE
            + "(" + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_NAME + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_SIZE + " integer not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_CONTENTTYPE + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_EXTENSION + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_CONTENT + " text not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_LABEL + " text not null,"
            + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_DATEUPLOADED + " date not null,"
            +FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE_USERNAME + " text not null)";




    public DatabaseWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if(newVersion>oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FUNTUBE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FUNTUBE_UPLOADFILE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling your app.

Comment: just remove `if()` statement and `onCreate(db); ` from `onUpgrade()` and reinstall your app

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

just change your DATABASE_VERSION  field to 2. it will start droping and recreating your table from the begining.